# Why is there a need for both Assignee and Assignees in GitHub?

Tags: github, github-api

Currently I experiment with the GitHub API, and I noticed the following: if you request an issue, it has both an **assignee** and a set of **assignees** - with the same properties as the **user** above. This feature was [introduced a year ago](https://github.com/blog/2178-multiple-assignees-on-issues-and-pull-requests), as it seems.

While I see the reason for having **assignees**, I don't understand why to have both properties, especially if, in the case of having assignees set, the first one will always be the assignee. Why isn't the set of **assignees** enough to store the information? One thing I can imagine is keeping **assignee** for legacy reasons, but what other explanation can be?

[Here](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/assignees/#add-assignees-to-an-issue) is a good example, right on the official GitHub page. As you can see, **assignee** is octocat, and after calling the `POST /repos/:owner/:repo/issues/:number/assignees`, the **assignees** will be octocat and the two new users.

Comment: Somewhat related Assignee vs Reviewer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41348853/342794

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen any official rationale from Github, but I think it's safe to say that it has to do with maintaining API compatibility.

They couldn't just change the `assignee` field from being a single user object to being a list of user objects since that would break existing API clients that assume it is always a single object.

They also didn't want to bump the API version to V4 for a small change like that.

So the solution is to add a new `assignees` field, existing API clients still works (although you don't get all the assignees) and new code that is being developed can use the new `assignees` field.